# Next.js: How to execute code after sending HTTP response?

Tags: javascript, http, asynchronous, next.js

In Express you can execute code after sending an HTTP response like this:

```
res.send()
await someAsyncFunction() // imagine this takes a very long time
```

In Next.js, at least when testing code in a local environment, the above works the same as express. However, once deployed on Vercel, the above code seems to stop execution after sending the HTTP response. I don't know if this is just because that's how their serverless functions are set up or what. So I'm forced to rearrange it like this:

```
await someAsyncFunction() // imagine this takes a very long time
res.send()
```

The problem with ordering it like that is if the async function is very slow, the response could time out before it gets sent back. There are situations where that is bad. Say I need to send a bunch of emails using a rate-limited API. That can take a long time. I need to send a HTTP response right away before moving on to the very slow process of sending all the emails.

Comment: Generally speaking node.js does not behave like that. Like you mentioned next.js (actually node) supports executing logic after `res.send()`. However you are executing your function on a serverless platform. It is possible that your vendor (Vercel?) kills your process (or maybe even the virtual machine the process run on) when it detects that your process has sent an HTTP response. They probably do this to save their computing resources. This is the normally expected behaviour for synchronous languages like PHP, Perl etc. but of course it's messing with your node.js code.

Comment: One work-around is to have another serverless function to do your background processing. Then pass the work you need to do in the background to that other function using whatever method your vendor support (eg. message queue, http request, notification service etc.)

Comment: did you try removing await...```someAsyncFunction()
res.send()``` it works with nodejs, not sure about nextjs

Comment: @slebetman after a little more Googling I found a helpful discussion on GitHub about the issue: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/14077 It appears that Vercel stops execution after sending the response, which is confusing because when testing locally it doesn't behave that way.

Comment: Most serverless platform try to avoid processes that run for too long (or even forever). This is due to the very architecture of serverless which runs all their customer's functions on as few machines as possible to save costs. AWS and Azure has a max timeout for this that you can configure.

Comment: Yes @slebetman in hindsight there's one particular thing I'm trying to do that doesn't fit serverless well at all, and it was kinda silly to try to make that work in that environment. Well, it'll work for now, it just won't scale.

Answer (score 1):

This is now supported but [in middleware only](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#waituntil-and-nextfetchevent).

> The waitUntil() method takes a promise as an argument, and extends the
> lifetime of the Middleware until the promise settles. This is useful
> for performing work in the background.

`middleware.js`:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextFetchEvent, NextRequest } from 'next/server'
 
export function middleware(req: NextRequest, event: NextFetchEvent) {
  event.waitUntil(
    fetch('https://my-analytics-platform.com', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({ pathname: req.nextUrl.pathname }),
    })
  )
 
  return NextResponse.next()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find explicit documentation explaining this behavior, but this GitHub discussion appears to confirm that you cannot execute code after sending an HTTP response if you are deploying on Vercel: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/14077

Thus I am stuck sending the response last.